# Proof under a suitable condition that $\lim_{x \to c}f(x) = 0$ implies $\lim_{x \to c}g(x) = 0$

Tags: analysis, epsilon-delta

I want to prove:
Take a real $c$, a $\delta > 0$,
and functions 
$f, g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.
If 
$$\lim_{x \to c}f(x) = 0$$
and
$$|g(x)| \leq |f(x)|$$
for all $0 < |x-c| < \delta,$
then
$$\lim_{x \to c}g(x) = 0.$$

The problem I have is that,
given an $\epsilon > 0$, 
I do not see from the given conditions a way to choose a $0 < \delta' \leq \delta$ such that
$$|x-c| < \delta' \Rightarrow |g(x)| < \epsilon.$$

Comment: Choose $\delta' = \delta$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since $$\lim_{x\rightarrow c} f(x) = 0$$ 
it is true, that
$$\forall_{\epsilon > 0} \exists_{\delta' > 0} \, |x - c| < \delta' \implies |f(x)| < \epsilon$$
Now let $\epsilon > 0$ and choose some $\delta'$ such that the above implication is true and $\delta' < \delta$.
Now we have
$$\forall_{x, |x - c| < \delta'} |g(x)| \leq |f(x)| < \epsilon$$

Comment: Thanks. I think my problem is: Then this would not hold for every $\epsilon > 0,$ because not every $\epsilon > 0$ can give a $\delta' \leq \delta$.

Comment: If $\delta' > \delta$, just make it smaller. The statement will remain true. (If something is true for a large environment of $c$, it will be true for a smaller environment of $c$ as well).